# Using One Kinect For Windows For Two Parallel Processes

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, kinect

I'm attempting to get a Microsoft Kinect for Windows working for a presentation. For skeletal tracking I am using a piece of software called FAAST and it seems to be working pretty well, however it does not have any voice recognition features. I wrote my own piece of software to make use of the Kinect's voice recognition but I found that I cannot run the two processes in parallel. Is this a problem that can be over come using the code in C#? I'm hoping it could be a modification to my C# voice recognition code but I would not know where to start and have not been able to find help on the internet.

Firstly, does anyone know if running two processes simultaneously with one kinect is possible? And if it is, how could I ensure that my kinect process allows for this?

I don't know which part of my code would be useful to you so I won't bother providing any at the moment. But if you require code samples I'd be happy to provide them.

Thank you.

Comment: Deleted answer below because I didn't see that you're using FAAST and there's no option to stream the audio out from there. If both the apps had source available, the option I provided might have worked.

Comment: Actually, try creating a KinectAudioSource/KinectAudioStream in your C# app. It might just work because the underlying unmanaged object will call NuiInitialize with a different set of flags - not NUI_INITIALIZE_FLAG_USES_SKELETON or somesuch. It might just work.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't currently have access to the kinect device I was working with, on Wednesday I will have it again and I will give it a try. If It works I'll be sure to report back here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, only one app can use the Kinect at a time via the SDK.  If you can use it just as a microphone, and just tap into "audio in" but not through the SDK, perhaps you can get around that.

Another option (if you have the source to FAAST) is to compile their stuff and your stuff together into a single app.  Based on the comments collecting, I'm guessing that isn't the case.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response but this appears to be true. We were able to use the audio sdk alongside FAAST. We ended up just using another 3rd party program (VAC) that apparently just uses "audio in", like you said.